# Finding CDF of $X^2$ and expected value

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the CDF of $Y=X^2$ given that the CDF of $X$ is$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0;&x<1\\0.1;&1\leqslant x<2\\0.5;&2\leqslant x<3\\1;&x\geqslant3\end{cases},$$but I am unsure how to do it. I tried defining it the following way:$$P(Y\leqslant y)=P(X^2\leqslant y)=P(X\leqslant\sqrt y),$$
but I am not sure what this would mean for my calculation. It seems logical for me to just put the $x$ value to the power of two… And this leads to my next question: If I want to calculate $E(X-\sin(X))$, is this calculated by just alter the $x$ values? Then my solution would be$$0.1(1-\sin(1))+0.4(2-\sin(2))+0.5(3-\sin(3)).$$
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X^2 takes the values 1, 4, or 9

The CDF of X^2 is the same as X with intervals  $x<1, 1\leq x<4, 4\leq x < 9, x>9$

And $\mathbb E[X - \sin(X)] = \sum_{i=1}^3 (i - \sin(i)) \mathbb P[X=i]$

You can read the probabilities from the CDF:

$$ \mathbb P[X=1] = 0.1, \mathbb P[X=2] = 0.5 - 0.1 = 0.4 $$
etc.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much!